# Azure Data Factory V2 Copy Activity - Save List of All Copied Files

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have pipelines that copy files from on-premises to different sinks, such as on-premises and SFTP.
I would like to save a list of all files that were copied in each run for reporting.

I tried using Get Metadata and For Each, but not sure how to save the output to a flat file or even a database table.

Alternatively, is it possible to fine the list of object that are copied somewhere in the Data Factory logs?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that you want save the output infos of the Copy activity into a falt file or a SQL table? [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6320/logging-azure-data-factory-pipeline-audit-data/) is some examples, but does not include the record source file name.

Comment: Hi @elasticSol, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: Hi @JosephXu It looks good. I reviewed it but couldn't have the chance to complete it. I am going to do so and let you know how it goes. I appreciate it!!

Comment: Hi @elasticSol, Are you having any problems?Let us know and solve it together.

Comment: Hi @JosephXu  I have 2 questions: 1. in Step 3, i get this error: Binary copy does not support copying from folder to file. -- 2. In the settings screen of ForEach activity, what did you type for "items"? Thank you again

Comment: Hi @elasticSol, I've updated the Step1 and Step3.

Comment: Hi @JosephXu - what did you type in the "Items" field in the "Settings" screen of the ForEach activity?

Comment: Hi @elasticSol, I type in `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`. Please see my updated part of the answer.

Comment: Hi @elasticSol, has the problem been solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Items:`@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`
[image]

---

---

If you want record the source file names, yes we can. As you said we need to use Get Metadata and For Each activity.
I've created a test to save the source file names of the Copy activity into a SQL table.

1. As we all know, we can get the file list via `Child items` in Get metadata activity.
   [image]
   The dataset of Get Metadata1 activity specify the container which contains several files.
   [image]
   The list of file in **test** container is as follows:
   [image]
2. At **inside** of the ForEach activity, we can traverse this array. I set a Copy activity named `Copy-Files` to copy files from source to destnation.
   [image]
3. `@item().name` represents every file in the **test** container. I key in the dynamic content `@item().name` to specify the file name. **Then it will sequentially pass the file names in the test container**. This is to execute the copy task in batches, each batch will pass in a file name to be copied. So that  we can record each file name into the database table later.
   [image]
4. Then I set another Copy activity to save the file names into a SQL table. Here I'm using Azure SQL and I've created a simple table.

```sql
create table dbo.File_Names(
    Copy_File_Name varchar(max)
);
```

5. As this [post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6320/logging-azure-data-factory-pipeline-audit-data/) also said, we can use similar syntax `select '@{item().name}' as Copy_File_Name` to access some activity datas in ADF. **Note**: the alias name should be the same as the column name in SQL table.
   [image]
6. Then we can sink the file names into the SQL table.
   [image]
   Select the table which created previously.
   [image]
7. After I run debug, I can see all the file names are saved into the table.
   [image]

If you want add more infomation, you can reference the [post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6320/logging-azure-data-factory-pipeline-audit-data/) I maintioned previously.