# Data Factory Childitem modified or created date

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a Data Factory V2 pipeline consisting of 'get metadata' and 'forEach' activities that reads a list of files on a file share (on-prem) and logs it in a database table. Currently, I'm only able to read file name, but would like to also retrieve the date modified and/or date created property of each file. Any help, please?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Joseph - thank you. I tried lastmodified, but it didn't apply for child items

Comment: Hi @elasticSol, I've updated my answer. The `lastmodified` property only can get the modification time of one file or folder. So we need to add another `get metadata` inside the `forEach` activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity).
We can see `File system` and `SFTP` both support the **lastModified** property. But we only can get the **lastModified** of one file or folder at a time.
[image]

I'm using `File system` to do the test. The process is basically the same as the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65161230/azure-data-factory-v2-copy-activity-save-list-of-all-copied-files), we need to add a `GetMetaData` activity to the ForEach activity.
This is my local files.
[image]

1. First, I created a table for logging.

```sql
create table Copy_Logs (
    Copy_File_Name varchar(max),
    Last_modified datetime
)
```

2. In ADF, I'm using `Child Items` at `Get Metadata1` activity to get the file list of the folder.
   [image]
3. Then add dynamic content `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` at `ForEach1` activity.
   [image]
4. Inside the `ForEach1` activity, using `Last modified` at `Get Metadata2` activity.
   [image]

In the dataset of `Get Metadata2` activity, I key in `@item().name` as follows.
[image]

5. Using `CopyFiles_To_Azure` activity to copy local files to the Azure Data Lake Storage V2.
   [image]
   I key in `@item().name` at the source dataset of `CopyFiles_To_Azure` activity.
   [image]
6. At `Create_Logs` activity, I'm using the following sql to get the info we need.
   [image]

```sql
select '@{item().name}' as Copy_File_Name, '@{activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified}' as Last_modified
```

7. In the end, sink to the sql table we created previously. The result is as follows.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

One way , I can think of is please add a  new Getmetdata inside the FE loop and use paramterized dataset and pass a filename as the paramter . The below animation should helped , I did tested the same .
HTH .
[image]