# Azure Data Factory ADF data pipeline to include filename in copy data to sql databse

Tags: azure, filenames, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I’m trying to create a pipeline on Azure data factory.
The pipeline pick up a file from azure file store and copies the data to a sql table. It works fine using a copy data task, but I want to include the name of the file in a column in the sql table.
Is this possible?

Comment: Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65638861/13979487) helpful for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Copy activity in Azure Data Factory v2 does have the ability to add extra columns such as variables and filepaths at run time.  Use variables like `$$FILEPATH`:

[image: filepaths]

See the official docs for more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy